# docker: vimagick/stunnel ==> /entrypoint.sh: line 21: openssl: not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openssl, vpn, stunnel

I am working on a ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS VM, where I have docker and docker-compose installed.

I am using a vimagick / stunnel image to build a tunnel against a client for quickFix services.

Problem: In a new installation, when I raise the docker-compose file, throw the following error:

```
tunnel_primary_1  | chmod: stunnel.pem: No such file or directory
tunnel_primary_1  | [ ] Clients allowed=512000
tunnel_primary_1  | [.] stunnel 5.56 on x86_64-alpine-linux-musl platform
tunnel_primary_1  | [.] Compiled/running with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
tunnel_primary_1  | [.] Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6 TLS:ENGINE,OCSP,PSK,SNI
tunnel_primary_1  | [ ] errno: (*__errno_location())
tunnel_primary_1  | [.] Reading configuration from file /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
tunnel_primary_1  | [.] UTF-8 byte order mark not detected
tunnel_primary_1  | [ ] No PRNG seeding was required
tunnel_primary_1  | [ ] Initializing service [quickfix]
tunnel_primary_1  | [ ] Ciphers: HIGH:!aNULL:!SSLv2:!DH:!kDHEPSK
tunnel_primary_1  | [ ] TLSv1.3 ciphersuites: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
tunnel_primary_1  | [ ] TLS options: 0x02100004 (+0x00000000, -0x00000000)
tunnel_primary_1  | [ ] Loading certificate from file: /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
tunnel_primary_1  | [!] error queue: ssl/ssl_rsa.c:615: error:140DC002:SSL routines:use_certificate_chain_file:system lib
tunnel_primary_1  | [!] error queue: crypto/bio/bss_file.c:290: error:20074002:BIO routines:file_ctrl:system lib
tunnel_primary_1  | [!] SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file: crypto/bio/bss_file.c:288: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
tunnel_primary_1  | [!] Service [quickfix]: Failed to initialize TLS context
tunnel_primary_1  | [ ] Deallocating section defaults
prueba1_tunnel_primary_1 exited with code 1
```

This is mi docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

 tunnel_primary:
   image: vimagick/stunnel
   ports:
     - "6789:6789"
   environment:
     - CLIENT=yes
     - SERVICE=quickfix
     - ACCEPT=0.0.0.0:6789
     - CONNECT=11.11.11.11:1234
   logging:
     driver: "json-file"
     options:
       max-size: "1024k"
       max-file: "10"
```

In the VM that is in production it works and there is no installation dif. Yes, the image of docker vimagick / stunnel that I use in production is 7 months ago

Thank!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This docker image is broken since they switched to `libressl` (without updating their launch script that still uses `openssl`).

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/vimagick/dockerfiles/pull/125) fixing this issue that will (hopefully) be merged.

In the meantime you can fork the [repo](https://github.com/vimagick/dockerfiles) containing the docker file and modify `dockerfiles/stunnel/docker-entrypoint.sh` by replacing `openssl` to `libressl`.

I ended up recreating a new image on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/prokofyevdmitry/stunnel/v1/images/sha256-ef66f0efc0b25df704bc8e3c2160fc5c2488f37d4fc9b0aa0fe1b70386fc972b?context=repo), use `prokofyevdmitry/stunnel` instead of `vimagik/stunnel` inside your `docker-compose.yml` file